# Any techniques for coding a heat shimmer/haze with actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Are there any free heat shimmer/haze libraries that can be programatically applied to a bitmapData or movieclip object?

I would prefer if it weren't a pixel bender setup, but if it is, it is.

If there aren't, where would one start with this kind of technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I have yet to find a solution to this, and appears that at this point in time, none exists.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer would have been a filter. The only ready-made heatwave filter I could find is the one on Flash-Filter.net and that will cost you. Interestingly it looks like an animated blur effect if anything, which could be done programmatically. Using the inbuilt blur filter you could selectively blur parts of a bitmap and change the blur values/position on each frame. In the case of a movieclip you'd have to draw it to a BitmapData object first and then apply any blur effects to it. That's the simplest solution I can think of without using Pixel Bender, but it probably won't produce the same results as a well written filter.